# Where can I take practice test for magento 2 Expert Certification?

Tags: magento2, certification

I need to pass Adobe Certified Expert - Adobe Commerce Developer with Cloud Add-on soon.
Can please recommend resources where I can take some practice tests? Thank's for any help)

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Certified Expert - Adobe Commerce Developer with Cloud Add-on
**AD0-E716**

- You can take a look at the Exam Guide here: https://express.adobe.com/page/gHMvWEByL74qK/
- Adobe (Magento) provides a free exam for prepare this exam, you can test at:

https://scorpion.caveon.com/launchpad/ad-q-e716-readiness-questionnaire-for-adobe-commerce-developer-expert/ad-q-e716-readiness-questionnaire-for-adobe-commerce-developer-expert